# How to fix maximized window leaving empty space between Taskbar and bottom of window When using RDP to Windows 11?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Sometimes I get an empty space between a maximized window and the task bar when I use RDP to connect to a Windows 11 machine. Restarting the remote machine fixes it. But is it really necessary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It isn't necessary, but I don't think that's what you're asking. You want to to figure out how to make that not happen. I suggest editing your question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart "Windows Explorer". I go to Task Manager and restart "Windows Explorer" process.

Comment: This is likely a temporary solution.  File Explorer errors like this often have their roots in context errors.

Comment: It is temporary, it happens again from time to time. But it's better than restarting a remote machine risking it won't restart.

Answer (score 0):

> It is temporary, it happens again from time to time.

This issue with File Explorer is, as I noted, likely a context issue

(1) Try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.  Then save the result to a USB Key.  Navigate to the USB Key and run Setup. At the appropriate question, try Keep Everything. Allow the Repair to run.  This is akin to watching paint dry.

(2) If Repair fails, then there is more serious OS damage or User Profile damage.

Best approach for this is to fully back up and reinstall Windows 11 Fresh.